# Unhandled rejection error while trying to generate Blockapps bloc key

Tags: ethereum

When I follow [this guide](http://www.blockapps.net/dashboard/quick-starts/blockchain-keyserver) to setting up blockapps bloc, I get stuck at generating a key.

bloc genkey gives me this error consistently both on my VM as well as 2 other machines running Ubuntu 14.04

Unhandled rejection Error: faucet: HTTPQuery: Object /account?address=627e191e27ec231c7af2744ca80d076e9184e74a has no method 'startsWith'

Why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

This was tripping me up until I realized that Ubuntu 14.04 comes installed with ancient versions of nodejs and npm.

Check your version of nodejs and npm and make sure they're up to date before trying to install Blockapps.

```
nodejs --version
npm -v
```

To upgrade nodejs:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Once both are up to date, you should be able to follow [these instructions](http://blockapps.net/dashboard/quick-starts/blockchain-keyserver) to get up and running with Blockapps.

Comment: Note, Ubuntu 14.04 is more than two years old and only receives security updates. Consider running 16.04 in the future. Please also note, there is a [dedicated Stack Exchange site for Ethereum](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) for future references :)